# How to stop firestore offline

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a store application which requires a direct connection to the server before creating any process and I have noticed that Firebase stores commands on the device when devise is not connected to the network then it upload data when connected back.
I am trying to disable this through this code, but it does not work

```
Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   firestore.settings(
    persistenceEnabled: false,
  );
  return runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The firestore.settings() method could throw an error, which is currently swallowed. You could try the following to see if an error is thrown:

```
firestore.settings(persistenceEnabled: false).catchError((error) { print(error);});
```

Also, the settings method is an async method, so in theory, it could not be finished when your app starts.